# Error when building 'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method'

Tags: android, android-studio

I click on **sink project with files**
And Android Studio gives the following error

`Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_eek51wpg78awmmsksq9v7bu7q.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_eek51wpg78awmmsksq9v7bu7q$_run_closure5) values: [build_eek51wpg78awmmsksq9v7bu7q$_run_closure5@4f5c0dda]`

[image]